# Does InteropForms Toolkit 2.1 work with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, interop, vb6-migration, winforms-interop

I have a VB6 project that I'd like to eventually upgrade to something else. To that end, I want to start using InteropForms Toolkit 2.1, but the page states that the installer only works with VS2008 and VS2010.

Is there a way to use the toolkit in VS2012 anyway?  If so, has anyone been successful?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to make Interop Toolkit 2.1 work with Visual Studio 2012 (modified earlier response)

1. Modify the `InteropFormProxyGenerator.AddIn` file in the following folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs\Interop Forms Toolkit 2.1\Setup\User`
2. Add the following:

   `<HostApplication> <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name> <Version>11.0</Version> </HostApplication>`
3. Copy the file in `Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins` folder
4. Copy (merge) `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\*.*` to `Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\`

   AND

   Copy (merge) `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Basic\Windows\*.*` to `Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Basic\Windows`

Note: Documents may be MyDocuments

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in VS 2010 and it works. It needs Net 2.0 though, while we do our development in Net 4.x. To avoid compatibility and deployment headaches we dropped the InteropForms Toolkit then. I found that you do not really need it when you only want to use mixed VB6 and Net4 forms. For User Controls it might be another matter, but we do not use them interoperatively :-)

Answer (score 0):

Interop forms toolkit works in VS2010, not in VS2012.

I have installed both VS2010 and VS2012
Projects containing interop user controls created in VS2010, you can use and modify in VS2012
For adding new controls in a existing project, I use vs2012, I am copying/paste an old control and change GUIDs for com registration.

But maybe someone has a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Steps to make `Interop Toolkit 2.1` work with Visual Studio 2012

1. Modify the "InteropFormProxyGenerator.AddIn" file in the following folder:
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs\Interop Forms Toolkit 2.1\Setup\User
2. Add the following:

< HostApplication >
< Name >Microsoft Visual Studio< /Name >
< Version >11.0< /Version >
< /HostApplication >

3. Copy the file in "Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins" folder
4. Copy
   `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\*.*`
   to
   `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\`

   AND

   Copy
   `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Basic\Windows\*.*`
   to
   `Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual Basic\Windows`