# How do I use the Microsoft.InteropFormTools?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6, interop

I need to use the WinForms RichTextBox as an ocx in VB6.

Some years ago, there was an automatically wrapper tool (or at least a helper), the Microsoft.InteropFormTools.

Somebody even developed if further for VS2019:

https://github.com/hurcane/Microsoft.InteropFormTools.InteropFormProxyGenerator

I managed to compile it.

It now shows up in VS2019:

[image]

But I do not see any template or how to go on:

[image]

There is no template.

I have posted this question in the github project, but I am afraid it's dead.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801784/does-interopforms-toolkit-2-1-work-with-visual-studio-2012? It had instructions for an older version of VS, but maybe it would still help.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thank you, but I can't compare of take a closer look at what is going on there because VS2010 can no longer be found, and in the discussion, they use VS2010 as a start point and move files from VS2010 to VS2012.

Comment: @tmighty I can't help with the template issue, but what I can say is I've never used a template and I don't recall if the original Microsoft package even had one.  I just created the RichTextBox like you mention above using VS2022 and the original Microsoft package and it's really pretty simple.  The project has a reference to `Microsoft.InteropFormTools`, 3 additional files in the project tree, and a block of boilerplate code in the UserControl.  I know this observation doesn't help too much.  I also don't know if you are still having an issue, but if you are perhaps I could help guide you.

Answer (score 0):

To have the template, please copy all files in `Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\ to Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\`

Or if the folder 2010 isn't exists.

You can download it [here](https://www.ultraviewer.net/download/Visual%20Basic-Interop-Template.zip) , and extract all files to `Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual Basic\`